# Black screen shortly after entering BIOS

Tags: bios, motherboard

The computer is a Lenovo ThinkCentre M82 Desktop. CPU Intel Core i5-3470, 2x4GB DDR3, the motherboard is Lenovo is7xm. Recently, the computer is booting Windows quite slowly (Windows 10), but otherwise it works fine. There is a problem when I try to enter the BIOS. After pressing F1, the beep follows and shortly after this the BIOS window opens, but after approximately 4 seconds the screen turns black, whether I leave it on the home screen or use the arrow keys to move to the next sections in the BIOS.
Ctrl+Alt+Delete - F1 and the same happen. The same monitor works normally with another computer. I tried to change from VGA to Display port but the problem remains the same. A BIOS reset also didn't help. Help me if you can, please!

Comment: How are you reseting UEFI ("BIOS")? And if you have the option to use DP why are you insisting in the obsolete VGA?

Comment: Did you try another monitor?

Comment: If the Monitor is known to work, then you may have a motherboard problem (on board video chip).  Take the machine to a local computer repair shop.

Comment: No, I haven't tried another monitor, but this monitor works normally with another computer (and as I said with this one, after booting Windows).
I reset the BIOS with the jumper on the motherboard.
In addition, I was able to see that the date in the BIOS is today's - ie. the battery does not need to be replaced.

Comment: **If the date/time is kept after reseting then you aren't reseting at all**. So, instead of a jumper that's either incorrect for that purpose or isn't working for some reason, actually remove the battery for a few seconds.

Comment: Ok, I reset the BIOS - removing the battery for 10+ minutes (I first disconnected the cable from the computer and pressed the power button several times - to discharge the capacitors). I just put the battery in place and plugged in the power cord, which turned on the computer itself. Unfortunately, the problem remains the same. In fact, 2 times, after pressing F1 and the sound signal after that, it failed to enter the BIOS at all. On the 3rd and 4th time the computer managed to enter the BIOS and before the black screen appeared, I was able to see that the date has changed to 01.01.2010

Comment: Here, let me add a link to the video with this problem, which I managed to shoot - [Black screen shortly after entering BIOS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zD4Jhh12kKk)

Comment: Definitely a motherboard problem.

Comment: The problem turned out to be quite different - an incompatibility between the screen resolution required by the BIOS and the monitor resolution. A person from another forum told me about this problem. I have two monitors on hand - Belinea 1705S1 and Acer V243H. The second monitor is connected to my computer, and the first one I used for this computer. When I connected the Acer V243H to this computer, there were no such problems.